# How to delete files from applicationStorageDirectory?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to delete all files from  cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, and the problem is that I don't have the file names and every code that I found needs a file name.

Here's one example.

```
var path = "file:///storage/emulated/0";
var filename = "myfile.txt";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.remove(function(){
                  // The file has been removed succesfully
              },function(error){
                  // Error deleting the file
              },function(){
                 // The file doesn't exist
              });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should first list the files in that directory.

Comment: I think you can use this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394003/get-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-cordova
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937878/cordova-list-all-files-from-application-directory-www

And later delete the files.